# How to use global proxy settings for Direct Connection

Tags: proxy

I use a Proxy Server with LDAP Authentication for accessing internet. So I need to manually add Server Address and Port in every application that has to connect to internet.

Any methods by which I dont need to enter proxy address in my applications ?

( I have entered the authentication and proxy details at : apt.conf and changed the environment variables too. Firefox still asks for username pwd every time I connect)

Answer (score 0):

My proxy server Internet port is 8080 and the browser uses port 80

So I redirected port 80 request to port 8080

My eth1 port in local lan card and eth0 is the internet lan card

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```